# WCAG AA Compliance: select element does not have a value available to an accessibility API

Tags: accessibility, html-select, wcag

I have this code in html.

```
<select
    class="news-form-control custom-select"
    name="filterState" id="filterState" 
    role="listbox"
    contenteditable="true"
    aria-label="Enter state"
    aria-required="true">

    <optgroup>
        <option value="ALL">ALL</option>
        <option value="AB">AB</option>
        <option value="AE">AE</option>
        <option value="AK">AK</option>
        <option value="AL">AL</option>
    </optgroup>

</select>
```

An automated WCAG 2.0 Level AA Compliance audit produces this error:

**"This select element does not have a value available to an accessibility API."**

I **have** given a value to each option in the drop down, and to the select element. So why do I still get this error?

Comment: When your question is about an error or warning message, remember to say which tool you used.

Comment: @brennanyoung - thanks for cleaning up the question's broken markdown.

Answer (score 3):

This message comes from the HTML_CodeSniffer rules (which can be used on their own, or inside another tool such as [pa11y](http://pa11y.org/)). You can see the report by pasting your HTML code in the tool on the [HTML_CodeSniffer homepage](https://squizlabs.github.io/HTML_CodeSniffer/).

The first important thing to note is that it's reported as a **warning**, not an **error** as your question said. This isn't an outright WCAG failure, but it could be improved, so let's look at how to do that.

The warning relates to WCAG success criterion 4.1.2 "[Name, Role, Value](https://squizlabs.github.io/HTML_CodeSniffer/Standards/WCAG2/4_1_2)". This is about making sure assistive technology (such as a screen reader) has all the information it needs, so users can understand this control properly:

- **Name:** what this input is *called*, i.e. what piece of information the user is providing. In this case it's "Enter state".

  - Using `aria-label` for this is OK, but it only helps screen reader users.  I recommend replacing this with a visible `<label for="filterState">`, so *all* users can understand it.
- **Role:** what type of input it is. Here it's a drop-down selector.

  - Using a `<select>` element is enough. Remove the `role="listbox"` attribute - it isn't needed here. (The role attribute is mainly intended for writing custom controls in JS.)
- **Value:** This is the part which HTML_CodeSniffer issued the warning about.  It means the *current* value of the input, so that users understand what they have chosen.

  - For a HTML `<select>`, this means adding a `selected` attribute to an `<option>` element.
  - It's OK if the initial value is undefined. That's why it was classed as a warning, not an error.
  - In this case, since there is an "all" option, it will be helpful to mark that option as `selected` when the page is first shown to the user. *This will make the warning go away.*

I don't know why you have the `contenteditable` attribute here. You can quite likely remove that too.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the `optgroup`? It's only necessary if you want to group the options into subsets, but you only have one.

Maybe you are only showing one here, but have more than one in your code? But if you can live without it, this error message will most likely disappear.

If you *really* need `optgroup`s, a couple of things you can look at are:

- Add a label to the `optgroup`s, as suggested
  [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H85.html).
- Follow one of the listbox patterns, such as 'collapsible dropdown listbox' as suggested
  [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#Listbox).

Comment: This advice about `<optgroup>` is good, but your answer doesn't address the question, which was about the automated WCAG checker's message. It's also not helpful to send them to the ARIA authoring practices, when they are so close to succeeding with plain HTML.

Comment: the first link points to a plain (sans ARIA) HTML approach to using optgroup with proper labelling (essential for WCAG compliance), although -granted- it does not address the question as well as your answer.
(I didn't recognise that it was CodeSniffer output. Good catch!).